# Return values in table by number of occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Suppose I have a table of this sort:

```
id | name 
---+-----  
5  | aaa
6  | aba
7  | rrr
3  | aaa
2  | aad
1  | aaa
2  | aad
```

I would like to return all the names that appear in the 'names' column **at least** k times and how many times this value appeared, i.e if k = 1 then I will get:

```
name | num
-----+----
aaa  | 3
aba  | 1
rrr  | 1
aad  | 2
```

for k = 3 i will get:

```
name | num
-----+----        
aaa  | 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a condition on `count` in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT   name, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= k
```

Comment: awesome, what's the difference between this and Stidgeon's answer?

Answer (score 1):

i'd try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT = k;
```

or > k or whatever condition you like